# PHPIZE dont working on plesk whit 2 php version, imposible install extension

Tags: php

first sorry for my bad English, try to explain my problem as clearly as possible.

I have a strange problem on one of my servers,

I run a plesk 12 server,

I have 2 php versions.

The default php version 5.3 in /usr/bin

This working fine, and I can install modules here, PHPIZE version is:

```
/usr/bin/phpize -v
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
```

No problems there.

I have second PHP versión in /opt/php55

Here I cant compile any module:

```
/opt/php5.5/usr/bin/phpize -v
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
```

I run

/opt/php5.5/usr/bin/phpize
./configure
make 
make install

As always

But the module is installed in the incorrect path..

I edit all paths on phpize:

```
# Variable declaration
prefix='/opt/php5.5/usr'
datarootdir='/opt/php5.5/usr/share'
exec_prefix="`eval echo /opt/php5.5/usr`"
phpdir="`eval echo /opt/php5.5/usr/lib64/php`/build"
includedir="`eval echo /opt/php5.5/usr/include`/php"
builddir="`pwd`"
```

So I can compile modules for php5.3 but not for php 5.5, if I try to copy module to php5.5 modules dir I get error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: memcache: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
```

I try edit manually php.h zend_module.h zend_extension.h of php 5.3 but dont help always api number is API=20090626

Comment: Administration panels are off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build an extension for each version of PHP, follow like as below

For 5.3

```
/usr/bin/phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

And for 5.5

```
/opt/php5.5/usr/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/opt/php5.5/usr/bin/php-config
make
make install
```

Please edit to correct path. Above just example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I edit some lines on php-config and now working, that file also had some paths bad defined, like: include_dir="", so thank you very very much.

Comment: Your welcome my friend.